# Bittorrent and ISP

Tags: bittorrent, isp

Quick question..I switched my ISP yesterday and I immediately noticed that my torrent downloads are considerably faster now.

Is it possible torrent downloads were limited by my previous ISP?

Comment: Is the rest of your internet faster too?

Comment: No. The rest is the same speed as it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  You have not advised where you are, but it is common practice in many parts of the world to "prioritise" traffic.  Generally that means putting P2P traffic in a limited pool.

Decent ISP's publish this information, but a few hide it of-course, and then spin stories... and who is going to call them on it, as most users don't only download "Linux ISO's".

Also, P2P is quite expensive from an ISP's point of view, both in terms of resources used and in number of connections to be tracked on the routers.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how P2P is in any way more expensive than transferring the same amount of data between a client and a server? Only the NAT router in your LAN tracks connections; ISP routers usually do not need to, they only forward packets. (Aside from ISPs which do things like deep packet inspection to block BitTorrent... but then you essentially get a recursive argument, so this doesn't count.)

Comment: @grawity - He doesn't have to, because of the context of the statement, its the ISPs that feel that way.  They have already given their reasons for feeling that way.

Comment: @grawity - ISP's actually do track connections for accounting purposes.  Google "Netflow" which is an industry standard.  It is not needed for "IP to flow", but it is used for network analysis, accounting and reporting.  [ Also, packet tracking/inspection is useful for warding off DoS attacks etc ]